# Data transfer from one website to another

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, xss

I have two websites A and B both written in ASP.NET MVC 3. In website A there is a form which needs to be submitted to website B via POST method. The user has option to post it directly or after encrypting the values.

When I submit form without encryption it is simple form.submit() and I am able to get the values in website B using FormCollection object. But when user selects submit after encryption, I redirect to another action on website A itself where encryption occurs and then this encrypted data is placed in a hidden textbox in the corresponding view and then auto submitted on page load using jQuery to website B. But now I am unable to get any values in FormCollection object on website B.

What could the problem be? Is this happening because of any security feature to prevent XSS or something similar?

Comment: How is the data encypted/decrypted? Do you really need to submit the data client-side, therefore redirecting the user, or could you use a web service and call it server-side?

Comment: @roryf Using asymmetric encryption. It needs to be submitted to a webpage and not a webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its doubtful its from XSS protections - in that case you would see an exception.
Load up fiddler and make sure you see this data *in an element inside your form* that is getting posted to website b. if its there in the form that is being submitted - it should be available.

Comment: Thanks, using Fiddler I found that data was not reaching website B. Then I found that I was using id for my input controls. Changing it to name solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason for not using HTTPS and submitting directly the form to site B?

```
<form action="https://siteb/someaction" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="key1" value="value1" />
    <input type="text" name="key2" value="value2" />
    <input type="text" name="key3" value="value3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go ahead" />
</form>
```

If there is any reason in the case you are encrypting the values into a single hidden input and submitting the form containing this hidden field using javascript, only the value of the hidden field will be sent to site B. So for example if you had the following form:

```
<form action="http://siteb/someaction" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="some encrypted value" />
</form>
```

on site B you would fetch the encrypted value like this (don't use FormCollection, it's kinda ugly compared to view models):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string encrypted)
{
    // TODO: decrypt the encrypted value here to get the orginal string
    ...
}
```

And an even more elegant way would be to have a view model defined on site B and a custom model binder for this model that will do the decryption so that the action looks simply like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeViewModel model)
{
    // Directly use the model with all the fields in it.
    // The custom model binder will take care of the creating it
    // from the encrypted request string
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using HTTPS as well but user has an additional option to use encryption. In the encrypted scenario I have 2 hidden fields the encrypted value and the email id of the user. The email id is needed to get the user's private key for decryption.

Comment: @achinth, OK, but I still don't quite understand what security concerns are you trying to address with this *custom encryption scenario* that HTTPS doesn't already address?

Comment: form contains payment details which can be tampered with using browser plugins, if user prefers encrypted formatted the payment details which are read-only fields on the webpage are read again from db and then encrypted to ensure any tampering

Comment: not to mention reflected xss attacks on that page could get the plantext data - although one could argue this could be injected into site A as well, but at least here we reduce the attack surface to one app instead of two.